# Prevent special characters replacement into my DB with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

When I save `François` into my DB, it becomes `Fran&ccedil;ois`.

How can I prevent it to keep `François` ?

During my PDO connection I already use `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"`.

Thanks.

Comment: Please start reading here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: Also you want to take care _not_ to use any fancy "magical" functions like `htmlentities()` and the like...

Comment: Apart from that: why do you consider `ç` to be a "special" character? There is no such thing, there are only characters. UTF-8 currently defines a little above 112.000 such characters. None is "special".

Answer (score 0):

you can change charset to utf8 after starting PDO connection.

```
$pdo_object = new PDO(...);
$pdo_object->exec("SET NAMES 'utf8'; SET CHARSET 'utf8'");
```

Comment: No it's make the same.